# Excel vba using If & AND operator to check criteria not working

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to check a data with several columns. If the value in the first row of the each column is not what I assign, then it should exit sub.

The code is like this.

```
If Range("A1").Value <> "Doc No" And Range("C1").Value <> "Date" And Range("D1").Value <> "DocRef 3" _
    And Range("E1").Value <> "DocRef 4" And Range("F1").Value <> "DocRef 2" And Range("G1").Value <> "DocRef 1" _
    And Range("H1").Value <> "Debtor Code" And Range("I1").Value <> "Company Name" And Range("J1").Value <> "Area" Then
    MsgBox "Please use a corerct or new report to continue.", vbExclamation, "Wrong file format"
    Exit Sub
```

Now I change the value in A1 to "D" which is not "Doc No", but it run through.

Comment: You want `Or` not `And` in all those statements.

Comment: Oh...I get it now. Thank you!@ScottCraner